# What could be best MVC project structure with web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, api

I am an MVC.NET developer but never used API web service before in an MVC project.

I just want to know like for WCF services we use different project in the application usually. Likewise, what is best practice likewise for web API services and how they work with proxy design patterns extra?

In my current application I am using WCF services but I am keen to learn if API web service can replace it and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes , you can replace with API service.
For your project structure , you can refer below link content.

Implement ASP.Net Web API in ASP.Net MVC 5

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/implement-Asp-Net-web-api-2-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Comment: your link is very good thanks for the help,do you know how can we use proxy design pattern in combination with API

Comment: Sorry friend, i have no idea about this.Sorry